# Second promise does not run (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to learn promises in Nodejs. It happens that when i try to run two promises, the first one gets resolved, but the second one neither rejects or resolves.

UPDATE - promises does not run in order.

I tried both ways

```
let promiseConnectMongo = mongoDB.connectMongo();
let promiseCreateCollections = mongoDB.createCollections();
```

First:

```
promiseConnectMongo
.then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    return promiseCreateCollections;
});
```

Second:

```
promiseConnectMongo.then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    promiseCreateCollections.then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Both methods (not too fancy):

```
connectMongo: function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {
            if (err)
                reject("Failed to connect db.\n")
            else {
                dbase = db.db(dbName);
                resolve("Connected sucessfully to the database: " + dbName);
            }
        });
    });

},

createCollections: function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        console.log("Creating collections");

        dbase.createCollection("products", (err, result) => {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            console.log(result);
        })
            .then(() => dbase.createCollection("bag", (err, result) => {
                if (err)
                    reject(err);
                console.log(result);
            }))
            .then(() => dbase.createCollection("brands", (err, result) => {
                if (err)
                    reject(err);
                console.log(result);
            }))

        resolve("Collections created sucessfully");
    });
}
```

The output is:
[image: Output]

UPDATED OUTPUT 
[image]
Why the second Promise running first?

Comment: `createCollection` return promise only if callback is not passed, so there might be js error. Can you check by removing that callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some of this is going to be related to how you are using promises. Specifically, I se you following this pattern:

```
somethingAsync
  .then(Math.random())
  .then(x => console.log(x)) // undefined
```

You might expect the random number but what is happening is you are passing the result of calling `Math.random` to the `.then` callback. You are following this pattern in a couple places, e.g.:

```
.then(dbase.createCollection("bag", (err, result) => ...))
```

Using the method like this means it doesn't wait for your `createCollection` to finish. It just passes an `undefined` down the pipeline. That means `createCollections` resolves almost immediately with `undefined` as its value.

You can solve this simply by wrapping your calls:

```
.then(() => dbase.createCollection("bag", (err, result) => ...))
//    ^^^^^
```

Comment: Ok, so I wrapped as you said, and added a print ("Creating collections") at the beginning of the createCollection() promise. (Question updated).
However, it happens when I run the program, the output shows that same print first and then the "connected sucessfully...", even though it should resolve the connectPromise first, and the createPromise after, as shown in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I can see some issues in `createCollection`, if you want create multiple collections in mongo it can be done like this:

```
function createCollection (){
    return Promise.all([
        dbase.createCollection('products'),
        dbase.createCollection('bag'),
        dbase.createCollection('brands')
    ])
}
```

So you don't need to create custom promise and return it. This will create all three collection in parallel and will resolve when all 3 are done.

Then you can access response of them in then function like this:

```
createCollection()
.then(resArray=>{
   console.log(resArray[0],resArray[1],resArray[2])
})
```

But just keep in mind that if any one collection creation fails promise form `createCollection` will fail.

You can also create collection in parallel but I won't recommend that, as those are not depend on each other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It is much easier this way! However the dbase is undefined, as it seems to run this promise first as well, so when it tries to create a collection, a TypeError is thrown.